# jqgrid EditActionIconsColumn Events

Tags: button, jqgrid, action, editing

I have a jqgrid with EditActionsIconsColumn available to me in  the grid but I am trying to get a hold of the click events on the Edit, Del and Submit.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The `formatter:'actions'` is not yet good documented. The current version of jqGrid 3.8.2 support some options which you need. In [lines 394-466](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L394) of the jquery.fmatter.js of the current version you can see more.

What you need are `onEdit`, `afterSave` (on "Submit") and `delOptions.onclickSubmit` parameters.

To tell the truth I didn't use the 'actions' formatter before and to understand it myself write [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm) which solve also on all your questions. To make other easier to find the example in include the most important part of the code here:

```
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,           // init local data which will be edited
    editurl: 'clientArray', // we will use local editing
    colNames:['Actions', ... ],
    colModel:[
        {name:'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center',sortable:false,formatter:'actions',
         formatoptions:{
             keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
             onEdit:function(rowid) {
                 alert("in onEdit: rowid="+rowid+"\nWe don't need return anything");
             },
             onSuccess:function(jqXHR) {
                 // the function will be used as "succesfunc" parameter of editRow function
                 // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                 alert("in onSuccess used only for remote editing:"+
                       "\nresponseText="+jqXHR.responseText+
                       "\n\nWe can verify the server response and return false in case of"+
                       " error response. return true confirm that the response is successful");
                 // we can verify the server response and interpret it do as an error
                 // in the case we should return false. In the case onError will be called
                 return true;
             },
             onError:function(rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                 // the function will be used as "errorfunc" parameter of editRow function
                 // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                 // and saveRow function
                 // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow)
                 alert("in onError used only for remote editing:"+
                       "\nresponseText="+jqXHR.responseText+
                       "\nstatus="+jqXHR.status+
                       "\nstatusText"+jqXHR.statusText+
                       "\n\nWe don't need return anything");
             },
             afterSave:function(rowid) {
                 alert("in afterSave (Submit): rowid="+rowid+"\nWe don't need return anything");
             },
             afterRestore:function(rowid) {
                 alert("in afterRestore (Cancel): rowid="+rowid+"\nWe don't need return anything");
             },
             delOptions: {
                 // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
                 // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
                 onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, rowid) {
                     // we can use onclickSubmit function as "onclick" on "Delete" button
                     alert("The row with rowid="+rowid+" will be deleted");

                     // reset processing which could be modified
                     rp_ge.processing = true;

                     // delete row
                     grid.delRowData(rowid);
                     $("#delmod"+grid[0].id).hide();

                     if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
                         // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                         // TODO: deleting the last row from the last page which number is higher as 1
                         grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:grid[0].p.page}]);
                     }

                     return true;
                 },
                 processing:true // !!! the most important step for the "local" editing
                                 //     skip ajax request to the server
             }
         }},
        ...
    ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: When I used the code you suggested I get an error from Jqgrid.min.js :- 
"Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference". Can you tell me If I missed out something. Should I add extra column in the data ?

Comment: @Ganesh: Do you have the error in [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm) which I created for the answer? If you gat an error *in your code* then you should create the demo (in jsfiddle for example) which can be used to reproduce your problem. Only after that one can help you. The error `Unable to get property 'integer'` could be for example if you use old versions of jqGrid and don't included required locale file `grid.locale-en.js` before `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`.