# Custom jQGrid post action

Tags: jqgrid

I have an great sample of inline edit with jQGrid http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin.htm
There is two custom actions Edit and Delete.

I want to add one more custom inline Action, lets call it ToggleOnline. On this action i want to post all cells of the grid to the controller. Basically it will be kind of of edit action but it will set some default values to some columns.

The inline buttons was added like that:

```
{ name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 55, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                            delOptions: myDelOptions
                        }
                    }
```

than to add custom additional button i was using event `loadComplete:`

```
loadComplete: function(){ 
            debugger;
            var ids = jQuery("#Grid1").getDataIDs(); 
                for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
                    var cl = ids[i];
                    custom = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=jQuery('#Grid1').editRow(" + cl + "); />";
                    jQuery("#Grid1").setRowData(ids[i], { act: custom }) 
                } 
            }
```

but the custom button does not appearing at all.  And also i need somehow to post row data and also i need to specify custom action name(oper) to handle this action on server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I updated the demo for you. Now the http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin1.htm do what you need. (I removed from the code the second grid to hold the code smaller):

[image]

Some comments to the implementation. The actions formatter add "action buttons" elements inside a div. Every "action button" has the HTML markup like the following

```html
<div style="margin-left: 5px; float: left;"
     class="ui-pg-div ui-inline-del"
     onmouseover="jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');"
     title="Delete selected row"
     onmouseout="jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');"
     onclick="$.fn.fmatter.rowactions('10','List1','del',0);">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>
</div>
```

So to have the look of the custom button close to the original "action buttons" I do inside of `loadComplete` to following:

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var grid = $(this),
        iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'act'); // 'act' - name of the actions column
    grid.children("tbody")
        .children("tr.jqgrow")
        .children("td:nth-child("+(iCol+1)+")")
        .each(function() {
            $("<div>",
                {
                    title: "Custom",
                    mouseover: function() {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    mouseout: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    click: function(e) {
                        alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+
                              $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");
                    }
                }
              ).css({"margin-left": "5px", float:"left"})
               .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
               .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>')
               .appendTo($(this).children("div"));
    });
}
```

where

```js
var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
        var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'), i=0,l=cm.length;
        for (; i<l; i+=1) {
            if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
```

You can change the icon of the custom button from 'ui-icon-document' and change the code of the `click` event handle what you need I showed how you can get the rowid. Using it you can use `getRowData` method to get contain of another cells of the row.

**UPDATED:** The current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports easy way to implement custom buttons. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm).

Comment: If i move 'Actions' from the left to the right(currently it is first column, i made it last column) in that case could not see the new button there, any ideas? And also on doubleclick the edit and delete icons does not reflect the double click(does not getting changed) I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @Joper: It is very easy to explain. I used simplified code `"td:nth-child(1)"`. I updated the answer and the code to calculate the row index dynamically.

Comment: how could i remove delete inline action? I want to leave just edit and custom actions.

Comment: By the way I've posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676169/how-to-remove-inline-delete-action-in-jqgrid