# How to remove inline delete action in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I was trying to modify the sample from that question [Custom jQGrid post action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action) 
http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin1.htm to remove delete action like that:

```
ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
                    //...
                    $("div.ui-inline-edit", tr).hide();
                    //...
                }, 

onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    //...
                        $("div.ui-inline-edit", tr).show();
                    //...
                    }



  loadComplete: function () {
      $("div.ui-inline-del", tr).hide();
    }
```

But does not help.

Any ides how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should first hide all "del" icons inside of `loadComplete` and then add `afterSave` and `afterRestore` property to the `formatoptions` of the `actions` formatter:

```
formatter: 'actions',
formatoptions: {
    keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing
    afterSave: hideDelIcon,
    afterRestore: hideDelIcon
}
```

where

```
var hideDelIcon = function(rowid) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("tr#"+$.jgrid.jqID(rowid)+ " div.ui-inline-del").hide();
        },50);
    };
```

See the modified demo [here](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/admin2.htm).

Answer (score 12):

What about formatoptions:{..., delbutton:false, ...} ?

http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v70wa4jv.htm

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can add this:

```
 $('.ui-inline-del').each(function(index) {
                        $(this).html('');
                        });
or this:
$('.ui-inline-del').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    });
```

at the end of `loadComplete: function () {`
also change

```
.jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager1', { add: true, edit: false }, {}, {},
                  myDelOptions, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
```

to:

```
.jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager1', { add: true, edit: false, del:false }, {}, {},
                  myDelOptions, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
```

if you wish to remove the row delete option in the footer

Comment: This is too complicated. simply using `formatoptions:{..., delbutton:false, ...} ?` as stated in Anderson answer removes delete button