# Why a 404 error for editurl: 'clientData' when deleting a second row from jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Referring to a slightly modified version of a jqGrid local editing demo by user @Oleg  located here: http://www.dataactive.net/local_editing.htm
...after one row is deleted using either the rubbish bin icon in the lower toolbar or the Delete button on the top toolbar, the following error is given in Firebug:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.dataactive.net/clientArray"

@Oleg are you able to ascertain why this happens?

Now that that problem is solved with the row deletion, something else I observe (keeping in mind this is editing "local data"), when newly added rows are deleted they don't seem to vanish. Consider the myDelOptions code from your demo (@Oleg) which I'm trying to use in another script for a production purpose:

```
myDelOptions = {
    // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes
    // to the server so I use "processing:true" setting and delete
    // the row manually in onclickSubmit
    onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
        var grid_id = $.jgrid.jqID(grid[0].id),
            grid_p = grid[0].p,
            newPage = grid_p.page;

        // reset the value of processing option to true to
        // skip the ajax request to 'clientArray'.
        options.processing = true;

        // delete the row
        grid.delRowData(rowid);
        $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + grid_id,
                          { gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                              jqm: options.jqModal, onClose: options.onClose
                          });

        $("#list")[0].refreshIndex();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
        }, 100);

        calculateTotal();

        if (grid_p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
            if (grid_p.reccount === 0 && newPage === grid_p.lastpage) {
                // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                // which is the last page of the grid
                newPage--; // go to the previous page
            }
            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage}]);
        }

        return true;
    },
    processing: true
};
```

the `calculateTotal()` function which iterates through the row object, simply takes the numeric values of the columns of the rows that remain and re-totals them to a summary footer row but what is happening is that iterating through the row object of the grid shows the "deleted" rows are still there, in the array or something, and so a new total cannot be calculated because nothing seems to have changed, the rows are not actually deleted. I don't understand what actually happens when "delRowData" is used in context of local data but it appears to only "remove" the row from the visual grid but it is still part of the row object. And, stranger yet, if another new row is added, the "deleted" row(s) re-appear exactly as they were in addition to the new row. As you can see I have `refreshIndex[0]` and `trigger(reload)` but the row does not delete if `trigger("reload")` is there and `refreshIndex[0]` has no effect. Can anyone address any of this? Additional code required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Thank you! The trick on the example is to set `processing: true` as the part of  `myDelOptions`. At the first delete operation is everything OK, but the value will be reset to `processing: false` by another part of the `delGridRow` method at the second call of it.

The fix of the problem is very easy: one should just add additional line

```
options.processing = true;
```

inside of the `onclickSubmit` of the `myDelOptions`. See the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/local_editing.htm).

Comment: @Jerry Of Perth: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. It is **local** grid and for editing should no remote called be done. What problem you has? The only thing which I see in the demo: `var new_id = grid_p.records + 1;` line should be replaced to the `var new_id =  $.jgrid.randId();`. As I wrote the demo at the first time no safe method to generate the id existed in jqGrid. Later I suggested [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/some-bugs-in-new-code-from-github-grid-base-js-grid-filter-js-grid-common-js-and-grid-formedit-js/#p22486) new method which are now in jqgrid.

Comment: @Jerry: I modified [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/local_editing.htm) one more time and included the usage of `$.jgrid.randId()` in the `onclickSubmitLocal` method.

Comment: Sorry @Oleg didn't realize the character limit on comments. Thanks for your attention to this already. The changes to the demo I can't seem to add a new row with, do the jqQuery library references need to be updated for the new method(s)?

Comment: How can I ask another question in this same page which is related to the answer provided to the main question? It includes code and text.

Comment: @Jerry Of Perth: You are right with "Add". I tried to use `$.jgrid.randId()` in the code use jqGrid 3.8.2 and the `$.jgrid.randId()` exist only starting with jqGrid 4.0.0. I have to make a pause now, but I will post the modified code in the next hours.

Comment: @Jerry Of Perth: You can just modify your question any time. You can add text like "UPDATED" and add any code which you need.

Comment: @Jerry Of Perth: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithContextmenu3.htm). It uses jqGrid 4.1.2, jQuery 1.6.2, jQuery UI 1.8.14. It demonstrate how to use local form editing with context menu, advanced searching and the filter toolbar.

Comment: using bits of your most revised local editing demo code solved the problem that I amended my original question with. Works perfectly, many thanks for that.