# JQGrid row action menu

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way in JQ-Grid to display an icon for each row which will open a drop down menu with a list of actions/links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no standard implementation of the behavior. You can implement what you need with respect of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).

You can try to use `formatter:'actions'` as alternative way. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action/6627201#6627201) I shows how to extend standard actions buttons with custom buttons. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm)) I shows one more way how to implement very close behavior as `formatter:'actions'` do but with respect on another events.