# JqGrid Edit & Delete button with each row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i m using jqgrid with mvc 3, I want to add Edit and Delete button with every row of JqGrid , i have achieved this thing by the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793). But it is for inline editing, i want to open a popup widows when click on edit button.

How can i achieve this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use new [editformbutton: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) option which exists starting with version 4.1.0 of jqGrid:

```
formatter:'actions',
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    editformbutton: true
}
```

Comment: Where to define the edit URL ? on 'onEdit' or somewhere else ?

Comment: @Saad: Per default it will be used the `editurl` parameter of grid. You can use `editOptions` of `formatoptions` to define any options of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method. So if `url` property of the `editOptions` of the `formatoptions` are not defined the `editurl` parameter of jqGrid will be used.

Comment: is it possible to add a Add button (or a custom button) with edit and delete in "Actions" formatter ?

Comment: @Saad: Custom buttons are not supported directly by the 'actions' formatter, but if one will do some things manually it is do possible. Look at [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin1.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action/6627201#6627201).

Comment: Thanks i added a button , now i want to open a add form of jqgrid when click on this button, is this thing is possible ???

Comment: @Saad: everything is possible. You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for example. To have not so large font in the dialog you can use `html, body { font-size: 75%; }` for example.

Comment: the logic of adding the custom button isnt working fine in IE 8 , because of class: "ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom" . any idea ?

Comment: @Saad: Thanks! I fixed the code of http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestSamle/Admin1.htm

Answer (score 2):

Please find the colmodel below for editing:

```
 {
                    name: 'EditAction',
                    width: 60,
                    fixed: true,
                    search: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    resize: false,
                    formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: false,
                        editbutton: true,
                        delbutton: false,
                        editformbutton: false,
                        onSuccess: function(response) {
                            if (response.status == 200) {
                            }
                        },
                        extraparam: { oper: 'edit' },
                        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")'
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
data: second,
@*url: '@Url.Action("orders", "Home")',
datatype: "json",*@
colNames: ['name', 'description',  'url'],
colModel: [
{name: 'name',
index: 'name',
editable: true,
editrules: {required: true},
editoptions: {placeholder: 'Enter a Name'}
},
{name: 'description',
index: 'description',
editable: true,
editrules: {required: true},
editoptions: {placeholder: 'Enter description'}
},

```
        {
      name: 'url',
        index: 'url',
        editable: true,
         editrules: {required: true},
         editoptions: {placeholder: 'Enter url'}
}
        ],

    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'model',
    pager: '#pager',
    editrow:true,
    editurl: '@Url.Action("orders", "Home")',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "0"
    },
     searching: {
            loadFilterDefaults: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            searchOperators: true,
            searchOnEnter: true
        },
    caption: "Cars Grid",
    height: '80%',
    gridComplete: initGrid
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).