# Creating a custom 'actions' formatter - jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

I'm wondering if I can add a custom "actions" formatter with my own custom image. What I want to accomplish is to have a hyperlinked image on each row so that when the user clicks it a dialog opens up with further options.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's do possible. I described the corresponding solutions including working demos in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179993/315935) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627201/315935). You can define any action in the `click` event handler. For example you can open some dialog.

If you need just add column with the image you can follow the approch described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935). In the case you can use `onCellSelect` or `beforeSelectRow` callbacks to implement your custom `onClick` handler.