# How to add a custom button to a jqGrid row that does NOT select the row when clicked

Tags: jqgrid

This example from Oleg is very close to the behavior I'm looking for (the first button) but I want preserve whether or not it was highlighted if possible, and don't want to highlight a row and check on the check box if it was un-selected. Just to clarify, I will be popping a modal dialog if they click this button, it has nothing to do with editing the row.

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent highlighting of the row in which the custom button will be clicked one need just include `return false;` inside of `click` event handler:

```js
click: function(e) {
    alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+
        $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");
    return false; // !!!!!
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3_.htm) demonstrate the results. It's the updated version of the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179993/315935) and [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627201/315935) which you referenced in your question. Additionally I updated the code of `myDelOptions.onclickSubmit` based on the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935).