# Adding a custom icon to jqgrid action column with onclick event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm) is a demo to add a custom icon in Actions column of jQgrid. In my case if I add 3 rows gridComplete is called 3 times. So I am getting 3 custom Icons in 1st row , 2 in 2nd row and 1 in 3rd row. Is there anyway we can add custom Icons based on Row and Column???

```
gridComplete: function () {
                var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'act');
                $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
                    .each(function() {
                        $("<div>", {
                            title: "Custom",
                            mouseover: function() {
                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            mouseout: function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            click: function(e) {
                                alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+
                                    $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");
                            }
                        }
                      ).css({"margin-right": "5px", float: "left", cursor: "pointer"})
                       .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
                       .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>')
                       .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3_.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308820/315935). It uses jqGrid 4.4.4, but the same code (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3__.htm)) works for jqGrid 4.5.2 too.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! I successfully added the custom icon using the above Demo. Is there anyway we could open a pop up(with Textarea and save, cancel buttons) onclick of that custom icon. So that user enters some notes in text area and when he click save I want to save it to some hidden column??

Comment: @minnu4515: You are welcome! In the demo I bound separate `click` event handler and calls `alert`. Additionally I shown how to get `rowid` from the `e` parameter of the event. So you can display any jQuery UI Dialog or some other popup and call `setCell` or `setRowData` to modify jqGrid column in the same row (a hidden row too). You need just use `rowid`. So I don't see any problem in implementing your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the line:

```
$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
```

should be

```
$(this).find("tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
```

(removing the ">" before the `tbody`)