# How do I add a command column to jqGrid using the GridModel pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, grid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have searched and searched, and Trirand, despite offering a paid for product, offer almost zero useful documentation.

I am using server side code to build the grid model, i.e. a collection of `JQGridColumn` objects, but of course there is zero documentation for this object:

```
Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
            {
                new JQGridColumn
                    {
                        DataField = "Id",
                        PrimaryKey = true, 
                        Editable = false,
                        Visible = false
                    },
                new JQGridColumn
                    {
                        DataField = "FileName",
                        HeaderText = "File Name",
                        Editable = false
                    },
```

This is taken from the example they give. There are millions of answers in the mode of building the grid column with JavaScript, and I probably will eventually manage to translate one, but right now, can anyone answer my question please?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid is open source **JavaScript** jQuery-plugin. One can use it in commercial products under MIT license. The solution from [trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/) just uses the same JavaScript internally. You can mix it with any JavaScript code which you find for free jqGrid. I recommend you to open source code of HTML page generated by commercial jqGrid and examine the code. If you use

```
<%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "Grid") %>
```

then you will find

```
<table id='Grid'>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#Grid').jqGrid({....});
    });
</script>
```

It will give you the starting point for mapping one solution to another one.

Additionally I recommend you to examine the code of "Cell Formatters/Templates(custom)" which you will find under "Functionality" part of [the demos](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/). You will see that Controller can define column model with `CustomFormatter`. The `CustomFormatter` specify object with `string` properties `FormatFunction` and `UnFormatFunction` which values are global JavaScript functions which you define in the View part. In the way you can specify [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) which gives you the way of pacing *any* custom HTML fragment in the grid's column.

Comment: Thank you, I know I can do this, but then what did I pay for worth more that $50?

Comment: @ProfK: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. You can use *free open source version of jqGrid*. I do this for example. If you have many developers who not familiar with JavaScript, but who knows C# and Visual Studio good you can purchase commercial version jqSuite. I payed in the past for the version to support developers of jqGrid only, but I use the original open source version of jqGrid myself. You can make your choice.

Comment: my question was rhetorical. I know I can use the free grid and all its goodness, but my C# is much better than my JS, and I wanted I smooth integration using Razor and sever side code. I expected more from Trirand. I've got a lot more from other vendors before.

Comment: @ProfK: I'm not from Trirand. I knows JavaScript also not so long (about 3 years) and know C/C++/C# and other languages much more longer. Nevertheless I invested my time in studding of JavaScript which is *very other* as most classical computer languages. For example no block level variables, lifetime of variables, closure and so on. Without understanding of basics of JavaScript you can't produce good code. It's my personal opinion.

Comment: @ProfK: Your original question was about "adding a command column" to the grid which I understand as column having button or a link (`<a>`). To implement this in commercial version of jqGrid you can use `CustomFormatter` like I described in the second part of my answer. Alternatively you can just use the fact that internally are used the same JavaScript product jqGrid (see my first part of the answer). So you can use any solution which you find for free jqGrid.

Comment: @ProfK: For example you can use `formatter: "actions"` and custom action button like I described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6627201/315935). You need just use `jqGridLoadComplete` or `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` jQuery event (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2)) instead of `loadComplete` used in the answer.