# jqgrid saveRow not making ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

am getting there with jqgrid, although i am still unable to save row data to the server

my mini-app creates buttons for each row, which makes a call to a googlemaps geocode.
the geocode fills out a form on my page with the data returned.

i have 3 seperate form fields each with its own button so the user can update the row with a correct address, the rel of each button gets changed to the id of the row the geocode has just been performed on.
i have this function for the buttons:

EDIT--------------

I have changed my code to try and get the response from the saveRow
I donot see ANY AJAX CALLS BEING MADE in firebug if i alert the saveRow it returns false, 
I have tried putting an error function to catch the error, but this does not seem to get called.
Oleg entioned that there are multiple id's in the database, bu this is impossible as its a primary key autonumber.
i dont see the request to my server.php to update the record getting called.

```
$('body').delegate('#displayaddr_btn', 'click', function(){
    myID = $(this).attr('rel');
    myLat = $('#lat').val();
    myLng = $('#lng').val();
    myAddress = $('#displayaddr').val();    
    alert('ID:'+myID+' myLat: '+myLat+' myLng: '+myLng+' Addt: '+myAddress);
    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',myID,{ lat_mdt:myLat, lng_mdt:myLng, displayaddr_mdt:myAddress });
```

alert(jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID)
        jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID,
            {errorfunc:function(id, error){
                alert('there was an error in saveRow()- ID:'+id+' Error: '+error);
            }
        }); 
    })

nothing seems to happen the alert outputs all the info it should, but i see no call to the processing page  to update the record.

------------Update in response to Oleg-------------------------------

Hi Oleg thanks for taking the time, indeed there was an error in my php file for the update of the record,
this is now fixed, the output Number of keys: 4 matches number of values: 4my update = UPDATE mapdata_mdt SET idetp_mdt = 0,geoaddr_mdt = 'n11hl',active_mdt = 0,flag_mdt = 0 WHERE id_mdt = 1343 is code i have put in the php page, and is my expected output.

in fact the edit functions on the grid are working as expected:
my problem is when i try to run `saveRow()` from a button external to the jqrid.
the button's (3 of them) are generated underneath the grid, when the 'geo' button for the grid row is pressed)

This is where i am experiencing problems when the button is clicked `saveRow()` returns false,from what i can see the call to server.php is not even made, so i cant debug any response.

(I have not used WFC, ASMX web services of ASP.NET MVC before and dont want to complicate things at this point!!)

what am missing? [Test URL](http://www.focus-on-plants.com/admin/stokists/index_grid_search.php) 
(geocode the first record called TEST in the list to populate the formthen click one of the save buttons for the appropriate text field)

here is all my code:

```
function setAddrButtons(myID, mylat, mylng){
        alert(' setaddrButtons----ID:'+myID+' myLat: '+myLat+' myLng: '+myLng+' Addt: '+myAddress);

        $('#displayaddr_btn').attr('rel', myID);
        $('#revlook_btn').attr('rel', myID);
        $('#altaddr_btn').attr('rel', myID);
        $('#lat').val(mylat);
        $('#lng').val(mylng);   
    }
    //jquery grid stuff
   $('body').delegate('#displayaddr_btn', 'click', function(){
        myID = $(this).attr('rel');
        myLat = $('#lat').val();
        myLng = $('#lng').val();
        myAddress = $('#displayaddr').val();    
        alert('ID:'+myID+' myLat: '+myLat+' myLng: '+myLng+' Addt: '+myAddress);
        alert(jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID)
    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID,
        {errorfunc:function(id, error){
            alert('there was an error in saveRow()- ID:'+id+' Error: '+error);
        }
    });

    })
    $('body').delegate('#revlook_btn', 'click', function(){
        myID = $(this).attr('rel');
        myLat = $('#lat').val();
        myLng = $('#lng').val();
        myAddress = $('#revlook').val();

        alert('ID:'+myID+' myLat: '+myLat+' myLng: '+myLng+' Addt: '+myAddress);

        jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',myID,{ lat_mdt:myLat, lng_mdt:myLng, displayaddr_mdt:myAddress });
        alert(jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID)
    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID,
        {errorfunc:function(id, error){
            alert('there was an error in saveRow()- ID:'+id+' Error: '+error);
        }
    });

    })
    $('body').delegate('#altaddr_btn', 'click', function(){
        myID = $(this).attr('rel');
        myLat = $('#lat').val();
        myLng = $('#lng').val();
        myAddress = $('#altaddr').val();
        alert('ID:'+myID+' myLat: '+myLat+' myLng: '+myLng+' Addt: '+myAddress);

        alert(jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID)
    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',myID,
        {errorfunc:function(id, error){
            alert('there was an error in saveRow()- ID:'+id+' Error: '+error);
        }
    }); 

    })

    myGrid = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
        url:'data/stokistdata_s_json.php?q=3', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST", 
        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[50,100,150,200,300,400,500,600], 
        pager: '#prowed2', 
        sortname: 'name_mdt', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        gridview:true,
        sortorder: "asc", 
        rowNum:50, 
        scroll: true, 
        editurl: "data/server.php", 
        caption:"Stockist's and Orchid days",
        colNames:[
            'Actions',
            'id',
            'Type', 
            'Name', 
            'Geo Address',
            'Display Address',
            'Telephone',
            'Email', 
            'website', 
            'lat', 
            'lng', 
            'flag', 
            'description', 
            'active'
        ], 
        colModel:[{
            name:'Actions',
            index:'Actions',
            width:100,
            sortable:false,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'id_mdt',
            index:'id_mdt',
            width:15,
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            search:false,
            hidden: true, 
            editable: true, 
            editrules: { edithidden: true }, 
            editoptions:{readonly:true},
            hidedlg: true,
            key: true
        }, {
            name:'id_etp',
            index:'id_etp', 
            width:90, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            formatter:'select',
            editoptions:{value:{1:'Stokist',0:'Orchid Day'}},
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'select',
            sopt: ['eq'],
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Stockist',2:'Orchid Day'}}
        },{
            name:'Name_mdt',
            index:'Name_mdt',
            align:"left", 
            width:150,
            editable:true,
            editrules:{required:true},
            search:true,
            stype:'text',
            sopt:['cn']
        }, {
            name:'geoaddr_mdt',
            index:'geoaddr_mdt',
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'displayaddr_mdt',
            index:'displayaddr_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'telephone_mdt',
            index:'telephone_mdt', 
            width:80,
            align:"left",
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'email_mdt',
            index:'email_mdt', 
            editrules:{email:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'website_mdt',
            index:'website_mdt', 
            editrules:{url:true, required:false},
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'lat_mdt',
            index:'lat_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        } , {
            name:'lng_mdt',
            index:'lng_mdt', 
            width:40, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false
        }, {
            name:'flag_mdt',
            index:'flag_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All',1:'Flagged',0:'No Flag'}}//{value:":Both;1:Flagged;0:No Flag"}
        }, {
            name:'description_mdt',
            index:'description_mdt', 
            width:150, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            search:false,
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"30"}
        }, {
            name:'active_mdt',
            index:'active_mdt', 
            width:20, 
            align:"left",
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions: {value:{1:'Active',0:'Hidden'}},
            search:true,//
            stype:'select',
            searchoptions:{value:{'':'All','1':'Active','0':'Hidden'}} //{value:":Both;1:Active;0:Hidden"}
        }], search : {
             caption: "Search...",
             Find: "Find",
             Reset: "Reset",
             matchText: " match",
             rulesText: " rules"
       },

        gridComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
                var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' alt='Edit Location' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editGridRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                fl = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Find' alt='Find Location' class='findMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Geo' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:fl+gc}); 
            } 
        }
    }); 

    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",
        {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},
        {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500},
        {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:500}    // Add options

    ); 
    myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{defaultSearch:'cn',stringResult:true});
```

Comment: I wanted to write you about the problem before. It seems to me that you have problems in the **server side**. The request to the server seems be OK, but 1) your database has more as one item which has the same `id_mdt`; 2) the server response has `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` instead of some error code in case of error and post just the error message as the response.

Comment: thanks oleg, is strange in firebug under the network tab or console i dont see any request being made too the server.php where are you getting that response from?

Comment: @Oleg: I've put in 'alert(jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow(myID));' just after the setRowData,it returns false, how do i debug this method???

Comment: One have not enough place in the comment, so I'll write my remarks in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your [test URL](http://www.focus-on-plants.com/admin/stokists/index_grid_search.php) and traced with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) the results of the editing of the first row.

If I edit the first row of your grid and type 'test' text in the 'Name' field I could see that the jqGrid send to the server the HTTP POST request having the data

```
id_mdt=1343&id_etp=0&Name_mdt=test&geoaddr_mdt=n11hl&displayaddr_mdt=&telephone_mdt=&email_mdt=&website_mdt=&lat_mdt=&lng_mdt=&flag_mdt=0&description_mdt=&active_mdt=0&oper=edit&id=1343
```

The data contain the contain of all editable filelds and two additional parameters `oper=edit` and `id=1343` (the same as `id_mdt=1343`). Your server should just make the modifications and response with any successful HTTP code in case of success and with an error HTTP code in case of failed data update. You server response has as the header which start with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
```

and in the body having

```
Number of keys: 4 matches number of values: 4my update = UPDATE mapdata_mdt SET idetp_mdt = 0,geoaddr_mdt = 'n11hl',active_mdt = 0,flag_mdt = 0 WHERE id_mdt = 1343<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: growthConn in <b>E:\Domains\f\focus-on-plants.com\user\htdocs\admin\stokists\data\server.php</b> on line <b>137</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in <b>E:\Domains\f\focus-on-plants.com\user\htdocs\admin\stokists\data\server.php</b> on line <b>137</b><br />
```

So one can see many problems:

1. The text "Number of keys: 4 matches" in the response can be interpret as if the `id_mdt` is not a primary key in the corresponding database table because more as one data item exist having the `id_mdt`. You should verify design of you database.
2. The strange error messages shows that the update failed. You should examine the line 137 of the `E:\Domains\f\focus-on-plants.com\user\htdocs\admin\stokists\data\server.php` server code.
3. You should change your code so, that on error any [error HTTP code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) should be placed in the server response.

I don't use PHP myself so I can't gives you more exact recommendation, but it is clear for me that first of all you should search for the error in your server code.

One more remark. From the server headers one can see that you use Microsoft IIS 7.0 as the web server. Why you don't use WFC, ASMX web services of ASP.NET MVC of your site? In any way I should switch on the [compression](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression?showTreeNavigation=true) of both dynamic and static contain on the web server. This will improve the performance of the site. Additionally you should consider to change the code which you currently use in `gridComplete` to improve the performance. There are many alternatives. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074604/jqgrid-beforeselectrow-and-sortablerows-exclude-column-from-being-draggabl/6076774#6076774).  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) for example (in the last answer the performance and event binding part is important; the custom formatter can be replaced from links to buttons).

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that your next problem is that you try to use [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) just to post information about the row to the server. The `saveRow` post the information about the row which is in the inline editing mode so **after** the call of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). Together with other things the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) add the `editable="1"` attribute to the row (to the `<tr>` element) with the code like:

```
$("#"+rowid).attr("editable","1");
```

Close to the begining the [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) test wether the row which one try to save has the attribute. It not it return and do nothing.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you for your detailed answer, i will have a look at fiddler, i understand the php error's its just a cant see the call in firebug to see for myself, will try you suguestions

Comment: @Oleg: I really do appreciate your time, i've updated my question, under -----Update to Oleg
my problem is not with the functions integrated within the grid, its an external button that uses `saveRow()` it teturns false and does not seem to fire the ajax call

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High: I appended my answer.