# jqGrid - How to programmatically select a cell in cell edit mode?

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid, how do you select a specific cell if the grid is in cell edit mode (`cellEdit: true`)? I only see a `setSelection` method to select a row, but not a `selectCell` method to select an individual cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just use [editCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#methods) method. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048079/315935) provides you the corresponding demo. The last parameter of `editCell` allows you to edit the cell or just select it without editing.

Comment: It wasn't obvious that editCell would select also. Many thanks Oleg! Always a pleasure to read your answers.