# how to add action buttons to jqgrid like shown in demo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

how to add icon buttons to jqgrid rows like shown in this demo?

[demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm) is from my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793). You can just open in web browser the source code and see all. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) contain [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm) which demonstrate how one can add action icons in absolute another way.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. problem i had on the old demo is i couldn't find out where the icons come from

Comment: @Gihan Lasita: You are welcome! I hope that [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm) answered all questions where the icons come from: jQuery UI CSS which defines classes like 'ui-icon-pencil', 'ui-icon-trash' and so on.