# jqGrid with custom hyperlink in each row

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where i have a column with delete hyperlinks for each row, i just cant manke hyperlink to make an action like `onclick=\"jQuery('#list').deleteRow('" + cl + "');` when i used simple button

```
{ name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 100, align: 'center', sortable: false}],
gridComplete: function () {
    var gr = jQuery('#list'); gr.setGridHeight("auto", true);

    var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var cl = ids[i];
       be = "<a href style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' title='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "',{reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")'});\" >Slet</>";
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many implementation ways to do what you need. Could you append your question with your current code which uses jqGrid. By the way, I recommend you to look as [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904).

Comment: well, as far  as i understand the problem is that <a href> dont have onclick event, it has target event, whivch can send u to an other page. i editet my prev. post so the code is in there now

Comment: i want to have a link instead of button. but functionallity should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It I understand you correct you should

1. add some value to `href` attribute. For example `href='#'`.
2. You should insert `return false;` at the end of the code of `onclick` function. It will prevent default `<a>` behavior.

Comment: if i remove a in front of href then it is just text which shows up, instead of link, return false worked to prevent hyperlink to run through. so now problem is that i need to call on click event, since nothing happends when i klik delete

Comment: @Timsen: I don't wrote you **to remove** `<a>` I suggested to **add** any value for the `href` attribute. Try this one: `"<a href='#' style='height:22px;width:90px;' type='button' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').delGridRow('" + cl + "'); return false;\"  />";`

Comment: @Timsen: I wrote you to your previous answer about the `delGridRow` method. There are no `deleteRow` method in jqGrid. Is it *your* method which you wrote as jQuery plugin or you wanted do use some standard jqGrid methods like `delGridRow` or `delRowData`?

Comment: @Timsen: The same as what? Is `deleteRow` the same as `delGridRow` or the same as `delRowData`? Where is the corresponding code? Do you tried my suggestions? Do you have the results which you need? If the problem are still not solved you should post your current code, describe the expected behavior and the behavior which you currently have.

Comment: Okay, deleteRow is an acition inside of my controller class which is called when button is clicked. Yes it is the same code. where u helped me with delete button, but now i decided that an link instead of button looks more stylish for my solution. I have tryed the code. It stoppes a href to complete action, so i get a chance to see delete Window where i can select if i want to delete or cansel. But i cant get past that windows, since nothing happend if i press delete. Onclick event does not get fired.

Comment: Sorry my fold, as i can see code wasnt copy pased properly. Ive update the code with properly copy paste

Comment: I got it to work now, it was some small mistakes which i keep doing. code should look like this: be = "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "',{reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")'}); return false;\">Slet </>";