# jQuery-jqGrid - using responseXML and or responseText

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a page that utilizes jQuery and I am planning to incorporate jqGrid into the page also. The page will have a submit button that will write a row into a table, and when an onReadyStateChange occurs, it will initiate a callback function.  Within that function, the jqGrid will be reloaded/replaced.  The current code is as follows:

```
var myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myURL = myServer + myOtherInfo;

..... (other parameters are added to the myURL variable)

myReq.open("GET",myURL, true); // true=asynchronous, false=synchronous
myReq.onreadystatechange = mycallback;
myReq.send(null);


function mycallback() {
var data = myReq.responseText;
var xdata = myReq.responseXML;
```

Since the dataset is going to be extremely small, we have elected to simply re-create/replace the grid on the page. I know the data is getting passed back into the two variables (data & xdata) above.   As of now, I'm only passing one field back in the ResponseText & ResponseXML (a variable number of rows).  Ultimately, it'll be 3-5 fields.

How do you get jqGrid to use what is already in the `data/myReq.responseText` or the `xdata/myReq.responseXML` variables/objects?

I thought that you would use the `datastr` & `datatype` of `xmlstring` but that's not working like I thought. Partial jqGrid is shown below.  This is also contained in the `mycallback function`.

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
xmlReader: {
datastr: xdata,
datatype: "xmlstring",
root: "Row",
row:  "ContactName",
colNames: ["Contact Name"],
colModel: [{name:"ContactName",index:"ContactName",width:200,align:"right"}],
viewrecords: true,
caption: "My Grid"
}
});
```

I'm very new to both jQuery & jqGrid, and would appreciate any assistance or direction.

**Edit**

Below is a sample of the data I'm currently using (out of the Northwind database).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Rowsets DateCreated="2013-05-02T09:18:07" EndDate="2013-05-02T09:18:07" StartDate="2013-05-02T08:18:07" Version="12.0.6 Build(13)">
<Rowset>
<Columns>
<Column Description="ContactName" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ContactName" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="ContactName" /> 
<Column Description="City" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="City" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="City" /> 
<Column Description="Country" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Country" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="Country" /> 
</Columns>
<Row>
<ContactName>Maria Anders</ContactName> 
<City>Berlin</City> 
<Country>Germany</Country> 
</Row>
<Row>
<ContactName>Ana Trujillo</ContactName> 
<City>México D.F.</City> 
<Country>Mexico</Country> 
</Row>
<Row>
<ContactName>Antonio Moreno</ContactName> 
<City>México D.F.</City> 
<Country>Mexico</Country> 
</Row>
<Row>
<ContactName>Thomas Hardy</ContactName> 
<City>London</City> 
<Country>UK</Country> 
</Row>
<Row>
<ContactName>Christina Berglund</ContactName> 
<City>Luleå</City> 
<Country>Sweden</Country> 
</Row>
<Row>
<ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName> 
<City>Mannheim</City> 
<Country>Germany</Country> 
</Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Since my original post, I've gotten the data to appear on the grid, and am now experimenting with formatting of it.

Ultimately, I would like to add a submit button in each row of the grid which would allow the user to select a row and then click the submit button to re-add that row to the table (When that's done, I'd be using a date-time stamp as one of the columns).

Originally, I had been using the XMLHttpRequest to run a query & receive XML back, and using the onreadystatechange to initiate a callback function that would load and display the grid.

Comment: The usage of *separate* Ajax request to the server and the usage of jqGrid with `datatype: "xmlstring"` is bad way. It much better to use `datatype: "xml"` and allow jqGrid make the call. You can use `xmlReader` to inform jqGrid *how* it can read required information from the xml response returned from the server. If you would include XML data which returns the server I could help you with `xmlReader`. I don't understand the first part of your question (about and `responseText` & `responseXML`). The code which "create" jqGrid is wrong because you insert all options inside of `xmlReader` option

Comment: The responseText & responseXML part was wanting to utilize one of them since I already had the text & XML responses with the data.  I was wanting to use jqGrid to simply construct the datagrid from them.  I had figured out some of the "create" issues - I was looking at a sample that omitted all but the xmlReader.

Comment: you have to include *an example of the XML data* which returns the server. Only after that one can say which `xmlReader` should be used. About the usage of `responseXML` I can only repeat that I see no need of the code with separate usage of `XMLHttpRequest`. In the example the full response from `myURL` contains the data for jqGrid. Instead of the code you can use just `url: myURL, datatype: "xml", loadonce: true`. The other options of jqGrid (especially `xmlReader`) depends on the structure of XML response returned from the server. **Could you just append your question with XML data?**

Comment: XML Data has been posted & other info.  Please see above for edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `myURL` which provide per Ajax XML data in the form which you included in your question then you could use the following code:

```js
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "steve_o.xml",
    xmlReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "Rowsets>Rowset",
        row:  "Row"
    },
    colNames: ["Contact Name", "City", "Country"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "ContactName" },
        { name: "City" },
        { name: "Country" }
    ],
    rowNum: 10000, // no local paring of data
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    loadonce: true
});
```

The corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/steve_o0.htm) displays

[image]

You can very easy use local paging of data just modifying the code to

```js
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "steve_o.xml",
    xmlReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "Rowsets>Rowset",
        row:  "Row"
    },
    colNames: ["Contact Name", "City", "Country"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "ContactName" },
        { name: "City" },
        { name: "Country" }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    loadonce: true
});
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/steve_o.htm) have pager with the some buttons and one can use it for paging:

[image]

One can add very easy local filtering and searching functionality to the grid like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/steve_o1.htm).

You last requirement about some buttons in every row looks very close to [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). You can look [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) for some code examples.