# Custom Buttons in inline editing like we have in pagination div in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

Is it possible to add the custom button in each row while using inline editing in jqgrid like we have a provision to add in pagination div using .navButtonAdd() function? If possible can any one suggest how to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can define an "Actions" column with a formatter.
Look here [jqgrid EditActionIconsColumn Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793)
and here http://blog.anupamgupta.me/2010/05/enable-inline-editing-in-jqgrid/

Comment: Thanks RRk, this one i already tried but i dont want html buttons instead of that i want same pencil icon with caption like we have a provision to add threw navbuttonadd() function

Comment: Have you tried `<img src>` tag instead of `<input type="button">` in the formatter function? And of course - `<img>` has to be inside `<a href>` and provide a onclick handler to mimick a button click.

Comment: if i will use this one i have to write custom function for the same, which i dont want to use. I want to use the by default editurl property function for this. So simply i just want to append or change the caption of edit button icon which is coming by deafult

Comment: I have not tried this but look at this wiki link <http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing> inlineNav section. here is the relevant settings: `parameters = { 
   edit: true,
   editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
   add: true,
   addicon:"ui-icon-plus",
   save: true,
   saveicon:"ui-icon-disk",
   cancel: true,
   cancelicon:"ui-icon-cancel",
   addParams : {useFormatter : false},
   editParams : {}
}`

Comment: i have tried this one also already. if we use this, it is adding extra edit and delete buttons with caption but same caption is not reflecting in the row's edit icon. only icon is coming without any caption.

Comment: You then probably want to look at the source code for jqGrid and see what is going on. Here is the link to latest inlineedit.js file https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.inlinedit.js or go here to look at a particular js file https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/v4.4.5/js