# beforeShowform in inline editing

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

is it possible to fire the beforshowform event in inline editing, because as per wiki i m not able to find any solution to call before show form in inline editing with option editformbutton:true . Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline editing don't display any form. So usage of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) is not possible in inline editing mode.

You wrote about the usage of `editformbutton: true`. So you probably use `formatter: "actions"` with  the property. In the case you do use form editing. You can specify any form editing options inside of `editOptions` option (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types)). So the usage of `formatter: "actions"` should be like below

```js
formatter: "actions",
formatoptions: {
    editformbutton: true,
    editOptions: {
        beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
            alert("In beforeShowForm");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot oleg ,you made my day. Appreciated your help and command over jqgrid. one more question i have posted can u provide solution for that also.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to accept... i have posted this one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514520/custom-buttons-in-inline-editing-like-we-have-in-pagination-div-in-jqgrid

Comment: @user1996823: I reread multiple times [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514520/custom-buttons-in-inline-editing-like-we-have-in-pagination-div-in-jqgrid) and all comments to the answer. I still don't understand what you want to implement. What button you want add in each row? Why `formatter: "actions"` do not what you want? I personally don't like to place the same buttons in every row of grid because it spends the place on the page. I use mostly context menu with items generated from buttons of navigator bar (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460116/315935)).