# Override JqGrid Edit/Delete button CSS class

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, styles

In my JQGrid i needed to add Edit and delete buttons so that when the user click on those buttons user will be redirected to another page for delete and edit the specific record. Currently it's working fine but I've got a CSS issue with the buttons. How can i override the style of the buttons.

Here is my MVC View

```
 <title>jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC - Demo</title>
    <!-- The jQuery UI theme that will be used by the grid -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!-- The Css UI theme extension of jqGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />    
    <!-- jQuery library is a prerequisite for jqGrid -->
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- language pack - MUST be included before the jqGrid javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- the jqGrid javascript runtime -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/MyStyle.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myGrid = $('#list');
        $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '/JqGridClients/DynamicGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',

                colNames: ['ClientID', 'Address', 'Company', 'Name'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'ClientID', index: 'ClientID', search: false,  align: 'left', formatter: PKId_formatter },
          { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Company', index: 'Company', search: true, align: 'left', stype: 'select' },
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', search: true, sortable: true, align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn' ,'eq', 'ne']}}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                 width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'ClientID',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                caption: 'Clients',

            }).navGrid('#pager', { search: true, edit: true, add: false, del: true, searchtext: "Search" });

              $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });

              $("#list").setGridParam({data: results.rows, localReader: reader}).trigger('reloadGrid');
        });

       function PKId_formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="Client/Edit?id=' + cellvalue + '" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" ></a> <a href="Client/Delete?id=' + cellvalue + '" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" ></a>';
}

  </script>  

    <h2>Index</h2>

<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ui-icon` class for `<a>` elements inside of `PKId_formatter` function. So the `<a>` elements will have `display: block` CSS style. You can fix the problem in many ways. For example you can add `style="display:inline-block"` to `<a>` elements.

You should consider to use `formatter: "actions"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) for example) instead of usage custom formatter.