# jqgrid inline edit get ajax success response

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

Can any one help me to get ajax response after inline editing in the jqgrid? Below is my code in the jqgrid and I don't know how to get ajax success response after inline editing.

I have tried with "loadComplete", "gridComplete" and "afterComplete". 
These are working only after the grid loaded but not after editing the cells.

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
            "width": "640",         
            "hoverrows": true,
            "viewrecords": false,
            "gridview": true,
            "url": "es.php",
            "editurl": "es.php",
            "cellurl": "es.php",
            "rowNum": 10,
            "rowList": [10, 20, 30],
            "sortname": "id",
            "datatype": "json",
            "colModel": [{
                "name": "employee",
                "sortable": false,
                "index": "employee",
                "editable": true,
                "editrules": { required: true } 
            }, {
                "name": "age",
                "index": "age",
                "sortable": false,
                "editable": true,
                "editrules": { required: true } 
            }, {
                "name": "actions",
                "formatter": "actions",
                "editable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "resizable": false,
                "delbutton" : false, 
                "fixed": true,
                "width": 60,
                "formatoptions": {
                    "keys": true,
                    "delbutton" : false, 
                    "delOptions": {}, 
                }
            }, {
                name: 'id',
                index: 'id',
                "key": true,
                hidden: true,
                viewable: true,
                editrules: {
                    edithidden: true
                },
                    "editable": false
                }
            ],
            "postData": {
                "oper": "fsgrid"
            },
            "prmNames": {
                "page": "page",
                "rows": "rows",
                "sort": "sidx",
                "order": "sord",
                "search": "_search",
                "nd": "nd",
                "id": "id",             
                "searchField": "searchField",
                "searchOper": "searchOper",
                "searchString": "searchString",
                "oper": "oper",
                "query": "grid",
                "addoper": "wsadd",
                "editoper": "wsedit",
                "excel": "excel",
                "subgrid": "subgrid",
                "totalrows": "totalrows",
            },
            "loadError": function(xhr, status, err) {
                try {
                    jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog(jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap, '<div class="ui-state-error">' + xhr.responseText + '</div>', jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose, {
                        buttonalign: 'right'
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            },
            "pager": "#pager",
            beforeShowForm: function(form) {
              $(".ui-inline-del").remove();
            },
        }); 

         jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                "edit": false,
                "add": true,
                "del": false,
                "search": false,
                "refresh": false,
                "view": false,
                "excel": false,
                "pdf": false,
                "csv": false,
                "columns": false
            });
```

With the above, everything is working fine. But I don't how to get ajax response after inline editing is done. More than that, I am very new to the jqgrid. I think, I am using very basic jqgrid code. So Please suggest me to get the response.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways how inline editing can be used. You use [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) which uses inline editing internally. So you can specify the options of the inline editing inside of `formatoptions`. For example to process success response after inline editing you can specify `onSuccess` callback which have the same parameters like `successfunc` of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). The callback `onError` can be used in the same way as `errorfunc` of `editRow`. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) provides you example of the usage of the callbacks.

One more way to specify `successfunc` or `errorfunc` callbacks of inline editing is the usage of `$.jgrid.inlineEdit`.

One more way is the usage of `jqGridInlineSuccessSaveRow` and `jqGridInlineErrorSaveRow` jQuery events:

```
jQuery("#grid").bind("jqGridInlineSuccessSaveRow",
    function (e, jqXHR, rowid, options) {
        alert("successful server response:\"" + jqXHR.responseText + "\"");
        // in case of adding new row on the server you can return id
        // of the new row
        return [true, jqXHR.responseText];
    }
);
```

(I don't tested the code, but I hope I made no errors here).

Some small remarks to the code which you posted: You can remove `beforeShowForm` callback from the list of options jqGrid. The callback can be used in case of form editing and it should be used on another place.

One more remark: you can remove unneeded hidden `id` column if you fill jqGrid correctly. It's important to understand that jqGrid assign `id` attribute to **every row** of the grid (to `<tr>` elements). The value of the `id` attribute is the rowid. The existence of hidden `id` column can make only more problems especially if you allow to edit the data.