# jqgrid inline edit with inline button

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I need to edit the jqgrid row as below:

1) Edit button should apppear on each row. (at last column).
2) on click of edit button, inline edit should enable and (Save and Cancel ) button should appear.

Please guide me .

I found, many exmaple but, its all on SELECT ROW .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) in the last column. It's allow to add buttons which help to start inline or form editing depend of the used options (see `editformbutton` property). The options (specified in `formatoptions`) `editOptions` and `delOptions` are specific for form editing. All other options in `formatoptions` (`keys`, `onEdit`, `afterSave` and so on) can be used to configure inline editing. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) for a code example.

Comment: @Dhaval: I referenced in my answer [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm). It demonstrates the meaning of different callbacks. You should decide yourself which formatter option are good for your project.