# Jqgrid : Update the page after delRowData

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using delRowData to delete a record in the jqgrid with pagination.
When user deletes the record, the page is not getting updated with the next record pages
Below is the code snippet of the action column used in the colmodel

```
onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
if (cm[i].name === 'delete') {
     FlDeleteAction(iRow, rowid, iColumn, 'scroll37');
}

function FlDeleteAction(iRow, rowid, iCol, gridid) {           
    jQuery('#gridid').delRowData(rowid);
    if (jQuery('#gridid')[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
        jQuery('#gridid').trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:jQuery('#gridid')[0].p.page}]);
    }
}
```

implemented as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793)

But , in my case the grid is getting reloaded with the deleted record :(

Help needed Urgently !!
Thanks.